using dominated convergence theorem for this series
$$
\mbox{I have to find}\quad
\lim_{m\ \to\ \infty}\sum_{n\ \neq\ m}\frac{m^{2}}{n^{2}\left(m^{2} - n^{2}\right)}
$$
I thought I could use dominated convergence theorem using that
$$
\frac{m^{2}}{n^{2}\left(m^{2} - n^{2}\right)} \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}}
$$
for $m$ big enough and $n$ is a fixed natural so no problem is the bold line correct ?.

No. You need a domination for every term.

@geetha290krm how can I do that ?

Actually your inequality does not hold for any $n,m$.

What does $\sum_{n\neq m}$ mean? Are you summing from $n = 1$ to $n = m-1$, or are you summing from $n=1$ to $n =\infty$ and skipping $m$?

@JohnBarber  from $n=1$ to $\infty$

Denote $f_m(n)= \frac{m^2}{n^2(m^2-n^2)}$. We want to find a function $f$ satisfying $|f_m(n)|\le f(n)$ for all $m$. One immediate candidate of $f$ would be $f(n)=\sup_{m\in\mathbb Z_+} |f_m(n)|$ (and in fact, this is the smallest dominating function. So if this $f$ is no in $\ell^1$ then DCT would not work for this problem). Have you tried to compute this $f$?

@Asigan  I have tried to say that this  sup could be $f_{n+1}(n)$ but i find something asymptotic to $\frac{1}{n}$ and it does not work why?

@Dsrksidemath Well, you are right... We perhaps need other ways. Sorry I made a mistake while computing and thought this was OK.

Too long for a comment
In fact we can use the dominated convergence, if me modify the initial sum a bit
$$S=\sum_{n=1;\,n\neq m}^\infty\frac{m^2}{n^2(m^2-n^2)}=\sum_{n=1;\,n\neq m}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac1{m^2-n^2}+\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac1{m^2-n^2}$$
$$=\zeta(2)-\frac1{m^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{k(2m-k)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(2m+k)}$$
For $\displaystyle 1\leqslant k<m\quad k(2m-k)>k^2$, hence for any $k\geqslant 1$
$$\frac{\chi_m}{k(2m-k)}<\frac1{k^2}$$
where $\displaystyle \chi_m=1\,\text{for}\, k=1, 2,\,...\,m-1$ and $=0\,$ for $\,k\geqslant m$
According to DCT
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{k(2m-k)}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\chi_m}{k(2m-k)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\chi_m}{k(2m-k)}=0$$
The same story we have with the second sum, noting that
$$\frac1{k(2m+k)}<\frac1{k^2}$$
The limit follows.
We can also go from another direction to evaluate the desired sum.
Using the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1,\,n\neq m}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2-n^2}=-\frac{3}{4m^2}$
$$S(m)=\zeta(2)-\frac1{m^2}-\frac{3}{4m^2}$$
